# Clipping the required portion of the image using CSS

Tags: html, css

So basically I have an image of a sunset I want to use as my banner for my webpage but I just want to use a portion of it, not the whole image. I figured out how to clip the image to the size I want; now I'm just trying to figure out how I can reposition the image so that the portion of the image I want to be seen is displayed in my chosen clip size. Thanks in advance.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #banner {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      margin-left: 15%;
      clip: rect(8px, 960px, 200px, 0px);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img id="banner" src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/sunset/sunset-02.jpg">
    <h1>My Travels</h1>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `clip` is deprecated. Use `clip-path` and the dimensions you have mentioned inside is the coordinates for the image.

Comment: You should crop the image in an image editor except if you've different dimensions of clip in different resolutions. Otherwise it'd be a waste of bandwith, load time, etc _aka_ web performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying clipping to elements in CSS is `clip-path`

For example:

```
.element { clip-path: inset(10px 20px 30px 40px); /* Also can take single values to make all sides the same, or 2 values (vert/horz), or 3 values (top/horz/bottom). */ }
```

Codepen Example : [here](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/02e4ebad4c8d3beeb0dc4781a811a37c).