# Trying to remove a horizontal line in a bootstrap 3 table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, horizontal-line

I'm making a table in bootstrap and I'm trying to figure out how to remove the border that appears on the top for every row.

I'm recreating the Stack Overflow home page and for practice and I'm making the table of Top Questions. I'm using 2 bootstrap rows for each actual row. Since I'm using 2 rows to appear as 1 I need to hide the top border of the 2nd row.

I've tried 2 different CSS methods to try to get rid of it to no avail. Both are shown below along with the html:

```
<style>

.2nd-line {
    border-top: none;
}

.borderless td, .borderless th {
    border: none;
}

</style>


<div class = "row-fluid"> <!-- begin row 1 -->
  <div class = "col-md-9">
    <div class = "panel-body">
      <table class="table borderless">
        <tr class="warning">
          <td>
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              <p class = "top-questions-stats">0</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              <p class = "top-questions-stats">1</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              <p class = "top-questions-stats">13</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-6">
              <a href = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545349/clipping-the-required-portion-of-the-image-using-css" target = "blank"><h5>Clipping the required portion of the image using CSS</h5></a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="warning 2nd-line borderless">
          <td class = "2nd-line borderless">
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              <p class = "top-questions-stats">votes</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              <p class = "top-questions-stats">answer</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-1">
              <p class = "top-questions-stats">views</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-2">
              <p>tags</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-4">
              <p class = "asked">asked 29 secs ago Darryl Mendonez</p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr> <!-- end row 1 -->
```

Comment: Did you apply the style after bootstrap css? It should work.

Comment: Yes, my custom stylesheet is always the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.borderless > thead > tr > th,
.borderless > tbody > tr > th,
.borderless > tfoot > tr > th,
.borderless > thead > tr > td,
.borderless > tbody > tr > td,
.borderless > tfoot > tr > td {
  border-top: none;
}
```

This is how to do it without !important tag.

Answer (score 1):

Add the !important attribute to your second style.

```
.borderless td, .borderless th {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Great. Thank you that worked. Is it possible to do it without !important? I try not to use !important as much as possible.

Comment: I've not tested either approach, however, you could try using an 'inline' style on your html element(s). Or, you can modify the bootstrap style directly which is probably not a recommended approach.

Comment: I could try inline although I try to make it a practice of doing all my css in a custom external stylesheet.